# SSRS Export to Excel does not do expand/collapse of groupings correctly

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, excel, reporting-services

My report works and looks perfectly in the web viewer and looks great in PDF export as well. But when I export to Excel the exported file does not do the groupings correctly. The intent is to have a list of all employees and have their list of accounts underneath that is collapsible. However in Excel the entire report is grouped under one header and it collapses the entire report instead of allowing each header to collapse.

This is the proper way / web viewer:

[image: Web Viewer]

But excel is collapsing the entire report not just each header:

[image: Excel's view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this comment left here where the author mentions the way to do groupings.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/508823/reporting-services-2008-group-by-export-to-excel-duplicate-rows-csv-ok-pdf-ok

The easiest way I've found to "fix" this is to re-create your hierarchical groupings (and the rows contained). Starting from the detail row (assuming you still have one) select the row header, right click for the menu, add new parent group using the next hierarchical level up. This creates a fun column that is to the left of your previous content separated by the dashed line. Select the column, right click for menu and choose delete. In the following dialog just remove the row, not the group you just made. This leaves the grouping containing only the details row/group. Select the existing details row header again, right click again, and choose to insert row > Outside Above (or below as your need might be). This adds the row to the next outer grouping from the selected detail row, similar as how 2005 allowed us groupings.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly  SSRS 2008 can't deal with 2 level of grouping on the excel export (that was a confirmed bug), but i thought that was fixed either with SSRS 2008 R2 or a CU later on. Are you on the latest available version of SSRS ?

Comment: No, we have SSRS 2008 not 2008 R2. I managed to fix it anyway it really was just I had set up the groupings slightly incorrectly. :)